# Stream video hosted on a server onto a display

Tags: raspbian, video, server

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I am working on a project in which a video which is hosted on a server needs to be displayed on a LED screen via a Raspberry Pi. The Pi will receive the video from the server and will display it on the screen. As I am totally new on Pi, how shall it be done? Please provide me with some references, if possible.

Comment: There are many many videos and tutorials for video streaming. What have you tried?

Comment: Most of them were streaming videos using the Raspberry Pi camera. Some were simply streaming video from the device's memory. Tried building my project on those, but found myself in more difficulties.

Comment: Hmm. Roughly speaking, you're trying to watch something like YouTube on your LED screen?

Comment: Yes, but the video that will displayed will totally depend on the remote server admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video content can be delivered as a file or as a stream. If video is delivered as a file, then simply consult [standard Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/video/). However, [streaming video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) is much more complicated since it involves long-term coordination between the media server and the displaying Raspberry Pi. The simplest approach for displaying streaming video on a Pi is to use a web browser, which incorporates all required software.   If you cannot use a web browser, then you will need to use a Linux utility. Please search the Internet for "displaying streaming video on Linux".